# How can I highlight the cell which contains the error?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, styles

I have a `DataGrid` with four columns for which I have defined a style as well as a triggered style for the case the user enters an invalid value.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="ArialMT"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,0,0,0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="!" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works well and the complete `DataGridRow` is marked as faulty because I used this in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <local:CycleValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

Now I want to highlight the `DataGridCell` with the invalid value explictely additionally (setting the background colour). Hence, I defined another style:

```
<Style x:Key="cycleErrStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but this doesn't work.
When I set `<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false" >` to **false**, the style affects. It seems as if the `Validation.HasError` property has been reset after validation for the grid's row.

In the XAML I defined this:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TagCycle" Header="Cycle" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=RawTag.Cycle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=cycleErrStyle}" />
```

How can I highlight the invalid cell additionally to marking the row as faulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `Validation.HasError` attached property of the parent `DataGridRow`:

```
<Style x:Key="cycleErrStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="true" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```